# Initialize 2d array in Class

Tags: c++

How would I go abouts initializing a 2d array? It states that I need to have a bound for my dimensions for multidimensional arrays.

header:

```
Class MyClass{
private:
    long x;
    long y;
    long matrix[][];
public:
    MyClass(long x, long y);
}
```

source:

```
MyClass:MyClass(long a, long b){
    x = a;
    y = b;
    matrix[x][y];
}
```

This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: *Initialize* typically means "to fill with data", but that does not seem to be the case here.  It looks like you want to *allocate* a 2D array, but that would involve making some kind of change to `matrix`, which you are not doing; the closest is `matrix[x][y]`, which is a reference to a (for now) nonexistent element of an array.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but since x/y don't have values yet I get an error thrown at me.

Comment: You need to know the sizes at compile time. There's no way around that. Alternatively, you can implement a dynamically sized 2D array type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `std::vector<std::vector<long>>`:

```c++
private:
    long x;
    long y;
    std::vector<std::vector<long>> matrix;
public:
    MyClass(long x, long y) : x(x), y(y), matrix(x, std::vector<long>(y)) { }
};
```

Comment: @2501 The size isn't known at compile-time, so not in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll play around with it!  What does x(x) and y(y) do?

Comment: @Ipawnu43 `x(x)` initializes the data member `x` with the parameter `x` (different variable names could be used to make it clearer). [This is a member-initializer list.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a single `std::vector` of size `rows * cols` to contain your values. Then you can access a given `(row, col)` by strides:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix {
 public:

  Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
      : m_data(rows * cols),
        m_rows(rows),
        m_cols(cols) { }

  long operator()(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const {
    return m_data[row * m_cols + col];
  }

  long& operator()(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) {
    return m_data[row * m_cols + col];
  }

  // other methods here...

 private:
  std::vector<long> m_data;
  std::size_t m_rows;
  std::size_t m_cols;
};

int main() {
  std::size_t rows = 3;
  std::size_t cols = 6;
  long value       = 0;

  Matrix A(rows, cols);

  // fill
  for(std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    for(std::size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
      A(row, col) = value++;
    }
  }

  // print
  for(std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    for(std::size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
      std::cout << A(row, col) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Some advantages:

- You don't have to worry about memory management, as all is managed by the underlying `std::vector`
- All elements are contiguous in memory, and you can choose your storage order (I've shown row-major, but you may want column-major) to improve the performance depending on your access patterns
- Easily adapt your class to handle a template parameter and vary your type

Remember that in C++ the notation `A[M][N]` is only meaningful to the compiler, and will ultimately result in a linear segment of memory `A[M * N]` in row-major order.